# how to use DESC tablename in the databaselibrary of robot framework for the database instance of python code

Tags: python, robotframework

```py
def schema(A,B):
   DB = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("DatabaseLibrary")`
   sql = "desc" +"" + A`
   DBLib.query(sql)
```

When I am running this *py* file from *.robot* script, below the error

```
DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement.
```

Could you please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

just a hunch -
might need a white space character between desc and A
currently

```
A = 'mytable' 
sql = "desc" +"" + A
```

would generate

```
descmytable
```

change to

```
sql = "desc " + A
```

?

Comment: desc tablename  (here table name passed dynamically from excel)  is displaying DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: Are you able to post a copy / paste of the actual command generated?  I would also recommend not using a SQL*Plus command - rather interrogate the oracle internal data dictionary views - will post a separate answer

Comment: for other "select" commands python robo framework is executing smoothly.even in the oracle sql developer desc tablename works fine but through python code connecting the DB instance from RF i am getting the error. ultimately i want  all  column names,datatype n length (i.e describe) of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use elements of this query ?

```
sql = "select table_name
 , column_name
 , data_type
 , data_length
 , data_Scale
 , decode (nullable, 'Y', 'Yes', 'N', 'No') AS Nullable
  from all_tab_columns
 where upper(table_name) = '" + A.upper() + "'
   and owner = '" + YourOwnerVar.upper() + "'"
```

Will help you to qualify table owner also in an and clause, for belt and braces

Comment: @vijaya - ref your comment below "for other "select" commands python ..." The sql query above will provide this" - and will return results in columns that can be be applied to a DataFrame - where as Desc might not be as forthcoming - as it returns response in text form that will then need a parse. Good luck

Comment: empty results found for this query

Comment: Very welcome - apologies it took so many goes - the internal views are always live and worth learning - the view names and column names are different between databases implementations - but the the concept is near identical across them all - are you able to "approve"?